# 'IRQn_Type' and 'Tc' not defined errors compiling Arduino sketch

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm referencing the types IRQn_Type and Tc in my sketch (for the startTimer function found [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=130423.90)), but I get a compile error saying those types are "not declared in this scope".  Aren't these "built-in" types?  If not, is there a header I must include?

Comment: Dan, what are you trying to do, interrupts?

Answer (score 0):

Dan, if you're trying to do interrupts, here's a list from the Arduino SE site
and are define in gcc avr header files.  Same ones I use to program AVRs from C in Atmel Studio:

```
#define INT0_vect         _VECTOR(1)   /* External Interrupt Request 0 */
#define INT1_vect         _VECTOR(2)   /* External Interrupt Request 1 */
#define PCINT0_vect       _VECTOR(3)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 0 */
#define PCINT1_vect       _VECTOR(4)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 0 */
#define PCINT2_vect       _VECTOR(5)   /* Pin Change Interrupt Request 1 */
#define WDT_vect          _VECTOR(6)   /* Watchdog Time-out Interrupt */
#define TIMER2_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(7)   /* Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER2_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(8)   /* Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER2_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(9)   /* Timer/Counter2 Overflow */
#define TIMER1_CAPT_vect  _VECTOR(10)  /* Timer/Counter1 Capture Event */
#define TIMER1_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(11)  /* Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER1_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(12)  /* Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B */
#define TIMER1_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(13)  /* Timer/Counter1 Overflow */
#define TIMER0_COMPA_vect _VECTOR(14)  /* TimerCounter0 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER0_COMPB_vect _VECTOR(15)  /* TimerCounter0 Compare Match B */
#define TIMER0_OVF_vect   _VECTOR(16)  /* Timer/Couner0 Overflow */
#define SPI_STC_vect      _VECTOR(17)  /* SPI Serial Transfer Complete */
#define USART_RX_vect     _VECTOR(18)  /* USART Rx Complete */
#define USART_UDRE_vect   _VECTOR(19)  /* USART, Data Register Empty */
#define USART_TX_vect     _VECTOR(20)  /* USART Tx Complete */
#define ADC_vect          _VECTOR(21)  /* ADC Conversion Complete */
#define EE_READY_vect     _VECTOR(22)  /* EEPROM Ready */
#define ANALOG_COMP_vect  _VECTOR(23)  /* Analog Comparator */
#define TWI_vect          _VECTOR(24)  /* Two-wire Serial Interface */
#define SPM_READY_vect    _VECTOR(25)  /* Store Program Memory Read */
```

Happy to help with specific programming questions, or you can [check out this link on the Arduino SE site.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12382/where-is-documentation-on-arduinos-internal-interrupts)

Comment: I need a way to regularly poll some peripherals attached to my Arduino, so I used the startTimer method found here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=130423.90, which apparently uses interrupts.  However, it won't build for me.  Specifically the types 'Tc' and 'IRQn_Type' can't be found.  The example code doesn't reference headers that I can see, so I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Dan that page says `Re: Timer Interrupts on Due`  Unless you're using the Due model -- which has more timers and different header files, I don't think the material on that page is for you.  Why don't you pose the question as to what you're trying to do and let us/me help you out?

Comment: I am using a Due.  My question is: what might I be missing that a sketch containing the symbols Tc and IRQn_Type can't be found.

Comment: @Dan no idea, never saw "IRQ" anything before in connection with any Arduino. Tc might mean "timer/counter"c where c is one of the numerous timer/counter modules.  And IRQ might mean ISR(_event_) which is a common calling convention for labeling interrupt service routines.  But I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm compiling for an Arduino Due, but I didn't have that board selected under Tools | Board.  Once I did that I was able to compile.